# The problem with (else , elif) shows an error

Tags: python-3.x

I started learning Python. The video shows how to make a simple calculator. I rewrote it, but it gives me an error(invalid syntax)and highlights the letter E in first elif. Version 3.8.6. Thanks for understanding.

```
# calculator

what = input("What's up ?(+, -):")

a = float(input('1 ч '))
b = float(input('2 ч '))
if what == '+' :
     c = a + b
print('result' + str(c ))
elif what == '-' :
     c = a - b
print('result' + str(c ))
else:
      print('?')
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp5-XQFr_nk&t=2172s  The video I rewrote the code from ( 35:50 time)

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Please go over some tutorials and learn basic Python syntax... Indents are significant in Python so your `else` doesn't match any `if`... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Tomerikoo.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line `print('result' + str(c ))`, you're missing an indentation. This causes Python to think that there's nothing else other than the `if` statement. Then, it sees a `elif` statement, which is unexpected because there can't be an `elif` statement without an `if` statement. So, your code needs to have its indentation fixed:

```
# calculator

what = input("What's up ?(+, -):")

a = float(input('1 ч '))
b = float(input('2 ч '))
if what == '+' :
     c = a + b
    print('result' + str(c )) # fixed indentation
elif what == '-' :
     c = a - b
    print('result' + str(c )) # fixed indentation
else:
      print('?')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print('result' + str(c ))` statement is not indented into the body of the if statement, so the elif doesn't know what if it is supposed to refer to. Same for the other `printf` : needs to be indented so its part of the elif.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
what = input("What's up ?(+, -):")

a = float(input('1 ч '))
b = float(input('2 ч '))
if what == '+' :
    c = a + b
    print('result' + str(c))
elif what == '-' :
    c = a - b
    print('result' + str(c))
else:
    print('?')
```